# Clion on macos meet "Debugger process finished with exit code 15"

Tags: macos, debugging, clion

I'm using clion on mac Catalina 10.15.7. When I debug program with lldb by default, clion return an error "Debugger process finished with exit code 15".

Is there any way to avoid the error?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

add `127.0.0.1 localhost` in you hosts

Answer (score 0):

For MAC Users ->
add `127.0.0.1 localhost` in your hosts

sudo nano /private/etc/hosts

Answer (score -1):

I encouted this problem too and mostly this is caused by unhandled exception like access nullptr. use breakpoint to find it will fixed it.

I tried to reproduce it but failed, maybe It's a bug for clion, wish this helpful.